# Error al insertar mas de 1600 registros en Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

Tengo la siguiente instrucción que realiza una carga masiva desde un archivo Excel en el front, el problema esta en que me arroja el siguiente error: **ORA-01000: número máximo de cursores abiertos excedido’ en Oracle con Java (JDBC)** y solo esta insertando alrededor de 1600 registros.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JsonResult postPlazos(List<PlazoEntrega> plz) throws ParseException, SQLException {

    Conexion_prueba_desa conn = new Conexion_prueba_desa();
    Connection miConexion = conn.GetConnection();

    JsonResult result = new JsonResult();

    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < plz.size(); i++) {
            PlazoEntrega plazo = new PlazoEntrega();

            plazo.setSku(plz.get(i).getSku());
            plazo.setPlazo(plz.get(i).getPlazo());

            String query = "INSERT INTO tabla_name(SKU, PLAZO) "
                     + "VALUES('"+ plazo.getSku()+"' ,'"+ plazo.getPlazo()+"')";

            prep = miConexion.prepareStatement(query);
            prep.executeQuery();

        }

        result.setCode(200);
        result.setStatus("OK");
        result.setMessage("Datos insertados correctamente!");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        result.setCode(401);
        result.setStatus("Error");
        result.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result.setCode(300);
        result.setStatus("Error");
        result.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (prep != null) {
            try {
                prep.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                result.setCode(400);
                result.setStatus("Error");
                result.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

¿Hay alguna forma de optimizar la instrucción para que permita la inserción de mas registros?

Comment: Usar sentencias preparadas y solo pasarle el parametro necesario.. si no, hay 1600 cursores con ejecuciones de la misma instruccion...

Comment: Mira como se usa el *PreparedStatement* adecuadamente (con *?* placeholders). Y no estaría de más usar *executeUpdate* en vez de *executeQuery*

Comment: Cual es la estructura de Conexion_prueba_desa() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución era cerrar la conexión en cada interacción del For.

```
prep.close();
```

Así:

```
try {

            for (int i = 0; i < plz.size(); i++) {
                PlazoEntrega plazo = new PlazoEntrega();

                plazo.setSku(plz.get(i).getSku());
                plazo.setPlazo(plz.get(i).getPlazo());

                String query = "INSERT INTO tabla_name(SKU, PLAZO) "
                         + "VALUES('"+ plazo.getSku()+"' ,'"+ plazo.getPlazo()+"')";

                prep = miConexion.prepareStatement(query);
                prep.executeQuery();
                prep.close();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para solventar este problema debemos:

1. Incluir la librería actualizada

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

2. Actualizar java 8 a java 11
3. realizar la llamada usando EntityManagery @Transactional

```
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;
    
    
    @Transactional
    public JsonObject callStoreProcedure(String procedureName, String params) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        try {
            StoredProcedureQuery query = this.entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery(procedureName);

            query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("json_param1", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("json_param", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
            query.setParameter("json_param1", params);

             query.execute();

            String json = (String) query.getOutputParameterValue("json_param");
            jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            return jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson("{\"estado\":false, \"message\":\"error en el procedimiento Java\"}",
                    JsonObject.class);
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }
```